# d3.js, how to draw multiple circles at the same (lat,long)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a situation where I have to draw small circles  on a map at a particular (latitude,longitude), but I have them overlapping each other, and the last circle is only seen, and the others get hidden below the last one, is there an example I can see somewhere, please see the picture below and advice.
[Please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86P07.png)

Answer (score 0):

SVG is a single plane, which means if circles overlap each other then then only the top one will be seen.  So what you're asking for is technically not possible.

However, if you want to kind of "slide out" circles if they are directly on top of one another, you would have to modify the y value of circles if they are equal such that each of them would be able to be seen.

So if you have an array like this:

`[ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 1, y: 2 } ]`

you would have to manually group items with the same x and y values and then kind of modify the y values a little so they are like this:

`[ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 1, y: 2.1 } ]`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks link,Sorry for the delay,  I understand its possible if I change one of x or y or both a little bit, but I am thinking if I can show a number on the circle  , and when clicked on the  number, then some how show all the circles.